# How to map the required data of array of object which i got from api call to usestate variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

```
[
    {
        cases: {new: '+44', active: 216, critical: 1, recovered: 15364, 1M_pop: '35323', …}
        continent: "Asia"
        country: "Brunei"
        day: "2022-01-10"
        deaths: {new: null, 1M_pop: '221', total: 98}
        population: 443851
        tests: {1M_pop: '1562743', total: 693625}
        time: "2022-01-10T16:15:04+00:00"
    },
    { 
        cases: {new: '+2', active: 4, critical: null, recovered: 20, 1M_pop: '34', …}
        continent: "Oceania"
        country: "Solomon-Islands"
        day: "2022-01-10"
        deaths: {new: null, 1M_pop: null, total: null}
        population: 711920
        tests: {1M_pop: '6321', total: 4500}
        time: "2022-01-10T16:15:04+00:00"
    }
]
```

like this, i have got 236 array of object but i want only few data from it like country, continent, total case, etc and stored it in usetate variable which will be array of object only but it will have this data only

Comment: Look into [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1):

```
let response = [
    {
        cases: { new: '+44', active: 216, critical: 1, recovered: 15364, 1M_pop: '35323', … }
        continent: "Asia"
        country: "Brunei"
        day: "2022-01-10"
        deaths: { new: null, 1M_pop: '221', total: 98 }
        population: 443851
        tests: { 1M_pop: '1562743', total: 693625 }
        time: "2022-01-10T16:15:04+00:00"
    },
    {
        cases: { new: '+2', active: 4, critical: null, recovered: 20, 1M_pop: '34', … }
        continent: "Oceania"
        country: "Solomon-Islands"
        day: "2022-01-10"
        deaths: { new: null, 1M_pop: null, total: null }
        population: 711920
        tests: { 1M_pop: '6321', total: 4500 }
        time: "2022-01-10T16:15:04+00:00"
    }
];
let mappedResponse = response.map(obj => {
    const { country, continent } = obj;
    return {
        country, 
        continent
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand well you have an array with 236 entries. If that's right, here is what you can do:

```
const results = [
    {
        cases: {new: '+44', active: 216, critical: 1, recovered: 15364, 1M_pop: '35323', …}
        continent: "Asia"
        country: "Brunei"
        day: "2022-01-10"
        deaths: {new: null, 1M_pop: '221', total: 98}
        population: 443851
        tests: {1M_pop: '1562743', total: 693625}
        time: "2022-01-10T16:15:04+00:00"
    },
    { 
        cases: {new: '+2', active: 4, critical: null, recovered: 20, 1M_pop: '34', …}
        continent: "Oceania"
        country: "Solomon-Islands"
        day: "2022-01-10"
        deaths: {new: null, 1M_pop: null, total: null}
        population: 711920
        tests: {1M_pop: '6321', total: 4500}
        time: "2022-01-10T16:15:04+00:00"
    }
];

const newArray = results.map(m => {
   return { country: m.country, cases: m.cases }
})
```

Comment: brother I want to add this result in usestate hook variable and pass it as props in another component to display it in the table.